# Set one variable to true based on conditions

Tags: php

How can I set one variable to true based on other conditions. Here, instead of doing

```
if ($vara && $varb && $varc)
```

I'm something like below. Problem is, I'm just not getting something right. Can you please help me?

```
<?php

$onward = false;

$vara = 11;
$varb = 21;
$varc = 3;

if ($vara == 1)
{$onward = true;}else{$onward = false;}

if ($varb == 2)
{$onward = true;}else{$onward = false;}

if ($varc == 3)
{$onward = true;}else{$onward = false;}

if ($onward)
{
echo "Ok";
}else {echo "Not ok";}

?>
```

Comment: Only the last check is actually setting the value - the results of the earlier if statements are being over-written

Comment: Why would you want to do that rather than the first approach? It amounts to the same thing - it's just much more bloated.

Comment: We can only guess what your actually desired condition is. Please express it in words.

Comment: There is absolutey nothing wrong with your first approach. It's much cleaner.

Comment: There are 13 if(). So I thought it would be easier and cleaner to do it this way. More if() may be added or deleted. Using $onward makes it easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each of your conditions ignores the result of the previous condition. You need to include the previous state of `$onward` in each subsequent test:

```
if ($vara == 1)
{$onward = true;}else{$onward = false;}

if ($varb == 2 && $onward)
{$onward = true;}else{$onward = false;}

if ($varc == 3 && $onward)
{$onward = true;}else{$onward = false;}
```

This way, `varb` and `varc` are only tested if `$onward` is still true after the previous test.

This is a particularly ugly way of writing code. If you have three large conditions and you don't simply want to join them on one line as in your `$vara && $varb && $varc`, you should be writing it this way:

```
$onward = ($vara == 1)
$onward = $onward && ($varb == 2);
$onward = $onward && ($varb == 3);
```

Any time you're simply returning/setting something to true/false in the branches if your if statement, you should just be returning/setting the condition itself.

That is, this:

```
if (condition) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

should always be written:

```
return condition;
```

Comment: Thanks. I've decided to use your first solution. Works well.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is, you are overwriting the value of `$onward` in every `if`-statement. Just use

```
$onward = $vara == 1 && $varb == 2 && $varc == 3;
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for:

```
$onward = $vara == 1 || $varb == 2 || $varc ==3;
```

or

```
$onward = $vara == 1 && $varb == 2 && $varc == 3;
```

depending on your goal.

---

With this:

```
if ($varc == 3)
{$onward = true;}else{$onward = false;}
```

`$onward` will always be `false` if `$varc` is not 3.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you mean

```
if (($vara == 1) && ($varb == 2) && ($varc == 3))
{$onward = true;}else{$onward = false;}
```

or even

```
$onward = (($vara == 1) && ($varb == 2) && ($varc == 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

A better way of doing this:

```
if ($vara == 1) {$onward = true;} else {$onward = false;}
```

is this:

```
$onward = ($vara == 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the same variable each time, so the first two conditions are actually pointless.

I don't know why you'd want to do this over the first, more succinct approach, which will have the same logical effect:

```
if ($varc ==== 1 || $varc === 2 || $varc === 3)
    $onward = true;
else
    $onward = false;
```

Or even just:

```
$onward = $varc === 1 || $varc === 2 || $varc === 3;
```

Beware also of ever doing `== 1`. In comparisons, data are coerced to their truthy/falsy equivalents, so any truthy value will resolve to true in the comparison `== 1`. To test that something is literally 1, use `===`. (This is a good rule generally unless you know you explicitly want to test for value and not type.)

Comment: *"If `$varc` super equals `1`"*?